# Printing ArrayList contents of type Data gives the wrong output {Java}

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of type data(that stores a string called name and an integer called age). When printing the contents of the Arraylist, it prints the right age but the same name from the element that I've last added.
Here is the PrintCollection method

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class Lab5 {
  public static void PrintCollection(Collection<Data> c)
  {
    for (Iterator<Data> iter = c.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
    {
        Data x = (Data)iter.next();
        x.Print();
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
```

}

and here is the class Data

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Data 
{
    public static String name;
    private int age;
    Data(String n,int a)
    {
        name = n;
        age = a;
    }
    public String GetName()
    {
        return(name);
    }
    public void SetName(String n)
    {
        name = n;
    }
    public int GetAge()
    {
        return(age);
    }
    public void SetAge(int a)
    {
        age = a;
    }
    public void Print()
    {
        System.out.print(("("+GetName()));
        System.out.print(",");
        System.out.print(GetAge());
        System.out.print(") ");
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<Data> array = new ArrayList<Data>();
        Data x = new Data("Fred",21);
        array.add(x);
        Data y = new Data("Jo",43);
        array.add(y);
        Data z = new Data("Zoe",37);
        array.add(z);
        Lab5.PrintCollection(array);
    }

}
```

Comment: Your String `name` is declared static `public static String name;`.  All instances of the class share the same static variable. Remove `static`.

Comment: And you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: method names are written in camelCase, i.e. they start with lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the keyword `static` in this line:

```
public static String name;
```

Also it's better to make it `private` too, to preserve encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `name` is not an instance variable, it belongs to the class definition, and each time you access it, you are referring to the *same* object reference; while the `age` is an instance variable, which means, for every instance of the class, there will be a distinct copy/reference of/to a different object (which is experienced by your `GetAge()` [*bad naming.. use camelCaseForMethodNames*] call).

See how instance variables are propagated [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html#:%7E:text=When%20a%20number%20of%20objects,distinct%20copies%20of%20instance%20variables.):

> When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint, they each have their own distinct copies of instance variables.

Comment: In my excuse, this code is mostly copied from what my teacher coded xD I don't know why it has static in it and why there is no camelCasing